# Create Table using Schema of SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create table from the return schema of sql query. Here, sql query has multiple joins. 
Example - In below scenario, create table schema for column 'r' & 't'.

```
select a.x as r b.y as t
from a
JOIN b
ON a.m = b.m
```

I can not use 'select into statement' because I get an input sql select statement and need to copy the output of that query to destination table at runtime.

Comment: Looks like you are looking for insert into clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading your problem correctly, you're getting SQL from an external source and you want to run that into a table (maybe with data, maybe without). This should do:

```
use tempdb;
declare @userSuppliedSQL nvarchar(max) = N'select top 10 * from Util.dbo.Numbers';

declare @sql nvarchar(max);

set @sql = concat('
with cte as (
', @userSuppliedSQL, '
)
select *
into dbo.temptable
from cte
where 9=0 --delete this line if you actually want data
;');
print @sql

exec sp_executesql @sql;
select * from dbo.temptable;
```

This assumes that the supplied query is legal for use as the body of a common table expression (e.g. all columns are named and unique). Note that you can't select into a temp table (i.e. #temp) because the temp table only exists for the duration of the `sp_executesql` call.

Also, for the love of all that is holy, please understand that by running arbitrary SQL that a user passes in, that you're opening yourself up to SQL injection.

Comment: I understand the risk of sql injection and it is taken care by other service line team accepting user request.

Answer (score 0):

Use the into clause here. Like

```
Select col1, col2, col3 
into newtable 
from old table;

select a.x as r b.y as t 
into c
from a
JOIN b ON a.m = b.m
```

Comment: It is always better to create the structure first and then use so you need to use any condition which will never satisfy.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you cannot select into, but can you select into with 0=1 to create an empty table structure and then insert after that?

```
select a.x as r b.y as t
into TABLE
from a
JOIN b
ON a.m = b.m
where 0 = 1
```